# Compute $\int\frac{1-x}{(x-2)(x+3)}$ and $\int\frac{cos(3x)}{sin(3x)}$

Tags: integration

Compute $\int\frac{1-x}{(x-2)(x+3)}$ and $\int\frac{cos(3x)}{sin(3x)}$. I have no idea how to solve these 2 integrals, I've run out of ideas. The first one especially, I can't even start, not sure how to do it. I've done this for the second one:

I introduced a new variable $t$, $3x = t$, therefore $dx = \frac{dt}{3}$

Inserted into the integral: $\frac13\int\frac{cost}{sint}dt$, which leaves me with $\frac13\int cot(t)dt$ and then it stops for me, I tried Per-Partes, but couldn't come up with anything useful.

How do I solve these 2 integrals? They're driving me nuts.

Comment: Partial fractions, and $t=\sin(3x)$.

Comment: One question per post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints** : For the first one use partial fractions, noting that
$$
\frac{1-x}{(x-2)(x+3)}=\frac{-1}{5x-10}-\frac{4/5}{x+3}.
$$

For the second one there is an obvious change of variable.

Comment: Managed to solve the second one, but I'm still having trouble solving the first one, yes I used partial fractions, but then what?

Comment: @NejcPisk You ask "then what?". Maybe you should read the notes you took in your course to see if the teacher has done problems which look like the ones you are trying to solve. Or you may look in your textbook and look for similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:$$\int \frac{1-x}{(x-2)(x+3)}=\int \frac{-4}{5(x+3)}-\frac{1}{5(x-2)}= -\int \frac{4}{5(x+3)}-\int\frac{1}{5(x-2)}$$

Now apply $u=x+3$ on the first integral, and $v=x-2$ on the second.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first one has been well answered.
For the second one, as is shown in your attempt, let $3x=t$,
$$I=\frac{1}{3}\int \cot t dt$$
where
$$\int \cot tdt=\int \frac{\cos t dt}{\sin t dt}=\int \frac{d(\sin t dt)}{\sin t dt}=\ln|\sin t|+const$$